# Drag and drop ooxml into word using word web add-in

Tags: html, ms-word, office-addins

Im building a word web add-in.

One of the functionality i would like to implement is dragging and dropping xml into my document.

I tried several routes such as.

```
   <div class="row" id="testDrag" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
        Test Draggable element
   </div>

 <script>
 function dragStart(event) {
     event.dataTransfer.setData("ooxml", "{your ooxml paragraph here}");
 }
 </script>
```

Is there a way to drag and drop into word, something like this.